# BeautifulSoup: do not add spaces where they matter, remove them where they don't

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This sample python program:

```
document='''<p>This is <i>something</i>, it happens
               in <b>real</b> life</p>'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(document)
print(soup.prettify())
```

produces the following output:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   This is
   <i>
    something
   </i>
   , it happens
               in
   <b>
    real
   </b>
   life
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

That's wrong, because it adds whitespace before and after each opening and closing tag and, for example, there should be no space between `</i>` and `,`. I would like it to:

1. Not add whitespace where there are none (even around block-level tags they could be problematic, if they are styled with `display:inline` in CSS.)
2. Collapse all whitespace in a single space, except optionally for line wrapping.

Something like this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>This is
   <i>something</i>,
   it happens in
   <b>real</b> life</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible with `BeautifulSoup`? Any other recommended HTML parser that can deal with this?

Comment: A lot of this is going to depend on the white-space and display properties associated with the relevant CSS selectors when rendered. Furthermore, JavaScript might well be employed to modify said properties. There's no good way of doing this. (I recall this came up a few years back in https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin/issues/21#issuecomment-2799823)

Comment: BeautifulSoup's documentation states that all tags will be in their own line. However, it shouldn't be too difficult to override that method - https://github.com/bdoms/beautifulsoup/blob/master/BeautifulSoup.py#L693

Answer (score 4):

Because of the habit of `.prettify` to put each tag in it's own line, it is not suitable for production code; it is only usable for debugging output, IMO. Just convert your soup to a string, using the `str` builtin function.

What you want is a change of the string contents in your tree; you could create a function to find all elements which contain sequences of two or more whitespace characters (using a pre-compiled regular expression), and then replace their contents.

BTW, you can have Python avoid the insertion of insignificant whitespace if you write your example like so:

```
document = ('<p>This is <i>something</i>, it happens '
            'in <b>real</b> life</p>')
```

This way you have two literals which are implicitly concatinated.

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Soup's `.prettify()` method is defined as outputting each tag on its own line (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#pretty-printing). If you want something else you'll need to make it yourself by walking the parse tree.

Answer (score 0):

As previous comments and thebjorn stated, BeautifulSoup's definition of pretty html is with each tag on it's own line, however, to deal with some of your problems with the spacing of , and such, you can collapse it first like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

document = """<p>This is <i>something</i>, it happens
               in <b>real</b> life</p>"""

document_stripped = " ".join(l.strip() for l in document.split("\n"))

soup = BeautifulSoup(document_stripped).prettify()

print(soup)
```

Which outputs this:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   This is
   <i>
    something
   </i>
   , it happens in
   <b>
    real
   </b>
   life
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```